# Showing a relation between a function and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Sorry for the kind of vague title, I my self am not really sure where to go with this.

This is a graph problem. $\mathcal{E}$ is a set of edges such that $(x,y)$ is an edge between nodes $x$ and $y$.

$w_{(x,y)}$ is the weight of edge $(x,y)$.

We have

$\phi(\mathbf{z}):=\sum_{(x,y)}w_{(x,y)}(z_x-z_y)^2$

for any $\mathbf{z}=\mathbb{R}^N$

$d_y=\sum_{x\ \text{such that}\ (x,y)\ \in\ \mathcal{E}}w_{(x,y)}$

$D=\text{diag}\{d_y\}$

Which I assume means the diagonal matrix containing vector $\mathbf{d}$ on its leading diagonal which has elements which are the sums of rows of $w(x,y)$. But I am not really sure.

$W_{x,y}=\begin{cases}w_{(x,y)},& \text{for } (x,y)\  \in \ \mathcal{E}\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$M=D-W$

Show that:

$\frac{1}{2}\phi(\mathbf{z})=\mathbf{z}^TM\mathbf{z}$

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the notation a bit better, I don't quite understand what are you working with. What is $\mathbf{z}$? Is it a vector in some finite dimensional vector space? Is it a function and $z_x$ and $z_y$ is evaluating that function at the points $x$ and $y$? In particular, where do the pairs $(x, y)$ live? What do you mean with $\mathrm{diag}\{d_y\}$? Is $\mathcal{E}$ completely arbitrary?

Comment: As a first step, maybe work out what the general formula for $z^TMz$ is, in terms of the coordinates for $z$ and $M$.

Comment: Just updated some information, hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: @IsuckatMaths Please do not destroy your question after having it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $w_{(x,y)}=w_{(y,x)}$ (the graph is undirected), you can write
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(z)
&= \sum_{(x,y)} w_{(x,y)} z_x^2
    -2 \sum_{(x,y)} w_{(x,y)} z_x z_y
    + \sum_{(x,y)} w_{(x,y)} z_y^2 \\
&= 2\sum_{(x,y)} w_{(x,y)} z_x^2
    -2 \sum_{(x,y)} w_{(x,y)} z_x z_y \\
&= 2\sum_{x} z_x^2 \sum_{y} w_{(x,y)} -2 \sum_{(x,y)} z_x w_{(x,y)} z_y \\
&= 2\sum_{x} z_x d_x z_x -2 \sum_{(x,y)} z_x w_{(x,y)} z_y \\
&= 2(z^T D z - z^T W z)
= 2 z^T (D-W) z = 2 z^T M z.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Amazing! I need to get better at this sort of thing...

Comment: But then you will have to change your nickname